# Using the function 'math.radians()' cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

Tags: python, pandas, math

This is my code,why the error occurs?

[image: This is my code,why the error occurs?]

Comment: What is your variable `a`?

Comment: If `a['CA']` and `a['B']` came from a text file, they might be strings. Try using `b = f(float(a['CA'], float(a['B']))` ?

Comment: Please don't upload pictures of your code. Add your code formatted to your posts.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a function designed for floats to accept series.

Change your d = radians(c) to

```
d = c.map(radians)
```

To apply the radians function to every value in the c series.